# Why flee to Albania?

Tags: harry-potter

After his downfall Voldemort fled to Albania, where he met a number of important figures in his revival. Namely Nagini, Bertha Jorkins, Wormtail....He's been there before though when he found and enchanted the Diadem of Ravenclaw. I was wondering if this or some other reason was why he returned years later.

What is there in Albania specifically, or about Albania that made it Voldemorts hiding place while he tried to re-coalesce his essence?

Comment: From the movie "Wag the Dog": "What do you know about Albania?" "Nothing..." "Exactly!"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> ... And wouldn't those secluded Albanian woods have seemed an excellent refuge when, so much laterm Voldemort had needed a place to lie low, undisturbed, for ten long years?  - Harry Potter's light bulb, after speaking to the Gray Lady, in DH

Most of the world is pretty populated by this time, so finding a place to lie low wasn't as easy as in 1300s. One secluded, out of the way, out of civilization, where there are few magic users (due to low overall population) was known to him.

AND the place that he both knew very well - the road there as well as the place itself - AND held great symbolic significance for him as a birthplace of one of the Horcruxes, to boot.

Seems like a pretty logical choice.

Comment: Was that not a known place of hiding for him?

Comment: @Pureferret - known to him? Yes. To anyone else? No.